# HAProxy Strip First Part of URI

Tags: haproxy

Our web service accepts calls of the form:

```
GET myws.acme.com:8080/v1/myws/path/{id}
```

We have configured HAProxy in front of this such that it can accept requests on port 80:

```
GET myhapproxy.acme.com/v1/myws/path/{id}
```

This is accomplished via:

```
frontend my_fe
    mode http
    bind *:80
    use_backend ws-backend if { path_beg /v1/myws/path/ }

backend ws-backend
    mode http
    server s1 myws.acme.com:8080
```

This is the prod version.

Dev and test have different URLs.

We would like to be able to call the HAProxy server like:

```
GET myhapproxy.acme.com/myws-dev/v1/myws/path/{id}
```

or

```
GET myhapproxy.acme.com/myws-test/v1/myws/path/{id}
```

to differentiate the other environments.

We have tried:

```
acl is_dev path_beg /myws-dev/v1/myws/path
redirect location http://dev.myws.acme.com:8080
```

When using this configuration to call
    GET myhapproxy.acme.com/myws-dev/v1/myws/path/{id}

The URL in the browser changes to http://dev.myws.acme.com:8080
with a 404 Response